# Java 9 javax.money.MonetaryAmount (JSR 354): Unable to convert Pojo to XML and vice versa

Tags: java, xml, java-money

I'm using Rest Api call to convert Pojo to XML.

Below is my code snippet:

**TestAccount.java**

```
  import javax.money.MonetaryAmount;

    public class TestAccount {


        private MonetaryAmount paymentAmount;

private String accountNumber;


    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return this.accountNumber;
    }


    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }
        public MonetaryAmount getPaymentAmount() {
            return this.paymentAmount;
        }


        public void setPaymentAmount(MonetaryAmount paymentAmount) {
            this.paymentAmount = paymentAmount;
        }

        }
```

**Controller.java**

```
public class Controller extends BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/javaTest", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/xml" })
    public TestAccount testMoneyPackage() {
        TestAccount obj = new TestAccount();
        obj.setAccountNumber("101423");
        obj.setPaymentAmount(MoneyUtilityCls.of(10.898));
        return obj;
    }
}
```

when running the url on browser

**http://localhost:8080/api/javaTest**

**output:**

```
<OverdueAccount>
<accountNumber>101423</accountNumber>
<paymentAmount>
<currency>
<context>
<providerName>java.util.Currency</providerName>
<empty>false</empty>
</context>
<defaultFractionDigits>2</defaultFractionDigits>
<currencyCode>USD</currencyCode>
<numericCode>840</numericCode>
</currency>
<number>10.9</number>*****loss of precision*******
<negative>false</negative>
<zero>false</zero>
<precision>3</precision>
<scale>1</scale>
<positiveOrZero>true</positiveOrZero>
<positive>true</positive>
<negativeOrZero>false</negativeOrZero>
<factory>
<defaultMonetaryContext>
<precision>0</precision>
<amountType>org.javamoney.moneta.RoundedMoney</amountType>
<fixedScale>false</fixedScale>
<maxScale>-1</maxScale>
<providerName/>
<empty>false</empty>
</defaultMonetaryContext>
<amountType>org.javamoney.moneta.RoundedMoney</amountType>
<maxNumber/>
<minNumber/>
<maximalMonetaryContext>
<precision>0</precision>
<amountType>org.javamoney.moneta.RoundedMoney</amountType>
<fixedScale>false</fixedScale>
<maxScale>-1</maxScale>
<providerName/>
<empty>false</empty>
</maximalMonetaryContext>
</factory>
<context>
<precision>0</precision>
<amountType>org.javamoney.moneta.RoundedMoney</amountType>
<fixedScale>false</fixedScale>
<maxScale>-1</maxScale>
<providerName/>
<empty>false</empty>
</context>
</paymentAmount>
</OverdueAccount>
```

As you can see  When setting

> od.setPaymentAmount(MoneyUtil.of(10.898));

I'm getting loss of precision in XML as

`<number>10.9</number>`

Also what are those extra XML tags?

This problem occurs only with MonetaryAmount field otherwise code is running properly.
So, What is the Correct way to convert MonetaryAmount field to Pojo to XML and vice versa without losing precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you share the code of your MoneyUtil/MoneyUtilityCls class?

I am guessing the implementation of MonetaryAmount used is RoundedMoney with a default fraction digits of 1, which would lead to the described behaviour.

The solution in this case would be to make the Utility return another class(Money for example) or to change the number of fraction digits of the returned RoundedMoney object.

Comment: "The solution in this case would be to make the Utility return another class(Money for example) or to change the number of fraction digits of the returned RoundedMoney object."  It worked. Thank you.